# Angular input autocomplete

Tags: angular

HTML -

```
<div class="item">
                    <label>Mentor Name</label> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-input" input-autocomplete [items]="items2"
                            (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search User"
                              (selectEvent)="onSelect($event)">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

ts-

```
 applyFilter(val:string){
    this.search=''
    if (val.length >= 3) {
       val = val.trim();
       val = val.toLowerCase();
      this.commonAddEditTeamService.userList()
    .subscribe((res:any) => {
     this.items2 = res.map(x=>x.name); }
```

RES - [ 0: {id: "7B5B201E-35AA-48A1-B919-002445319F8B", name: "harman jain"}

1: {id: "EA6672BA-4F7A-4214-A37F-00716CE698C9", name: "me name"}

2: {id: "01F29920-9206-42DF-8151-00A6A080C501", name: "sonu sharma"} ]

app.module.ts -

```
import { AutocompleteModule } from 'ng2-input-autocomplete';
imports: [
AutocompleteModule.forRoot()
]
```

Want to autocomplete this input field while searching for name of users.

Getting error - Can't bind to 'items' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. Also autocomplete is not working!

Comment: if you are using autocomplete in feature module make sure you import autocomplete module in that feature module as well

Comment: @fastAsTortoise Tried that already. Still not working.